# firebreath firefox plugin not found MACOSX

Tags: macos, firefox, firebreath, browser-plugin

I have been following the following firebreath tutorial:

http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Mac+Video+Tutorial

And in the second video, After i have built my plugin and i am including the ScreenTutorialPlugin.plugin file in the /Library/Internet/Plug-ins section, it doesn't show in firefox, when i go check it in about:plugins, it just doesnt show. But in the terminal when i go check /Library/Internet/Plug-ins, it does show.

when i open a plugin file and it opens in the browser, it says that the plugin doesnt work.

i think this has to do with the file linking part ln -s in the /plug-ins section.

or could the reason be that i use 3 different browsers? safari,firefox and chrome.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

With the information provided it is difficult to be certain what your issue is, but here are a few things to consider / understand:

- FireBreath plugins are NPAPI plugins and thus should work on all three of the browsers you mentioned
- The path where it should be installed is "/Library/Internet Plugins", not "/Library/Internet/Plugins" and if you have actually placed it in the latter directory as you indicated and that isn't a typo then this is definitely part of your issue
- using ln -s should work if you create a symlink to the actual .plugin directory, but if it doesn't you can always try copying the file itself
- If everything built correctly you should have a binary called (plugin name).plugin/Contents/MacOS/(plugin name) where (plugin name) is the name of your plugin

Hopefully some of this helps; if it doesn't, please provide more information about what you have tried and we'll try to help some more.  What you are doing definitely should work -- I use plugins created by FireBreath on Mac every day.

Comment: Thank you, i deleted the file and copy the file.